# JHipster - Can I add websocket support to my existing generated application?

Tags: jhipster

I have an existing JHipster application that was generated without adding the websocket option. A need has come about for this functionality to be added to the application for a realtime data view, is there a way to bolt this functionality into my existing generated app?

I tried adding toggling on the websocket: false value in the .yml file and re-running yo jhipster but this did not add in any new files and the example user tracker was not added into the project so assuming this cannot be accomplished this way
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator is looking for settings in the .yo-rc.json file which is located at root level in the folder of your app. Depending on your IDE it can be that is not shown and you need to show it over otehr perspective or to view it in a terminal/cmd.
In the .yo-rc.json you will need to change the value of the websocket property from ***no*** to ***spring-websocket*** i.e.

```
"websocket": "spring-websocket",
```

Now when you run your generator it should generate the parts need it for websockets. Also have a look at the [jhipster doc for websockets](https://jhipster.github.io/using-websockets/)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I was placing in "websocket": true instead of the above which is why it wasn't working! Thanks again